# WSO2 Byte array

Tags: http-headers, wso2, wso2-esb

is there any way to send a byte array (pdf) back from backend service with wso2esb using XML?

I mean, do a request to a backend service and send the response back to front end via esb as byte array (.pdf).

Comment: check MTOM with WSO2 ESB